# CSS tables white border

Tags: css, css-tables

I have problems with CSS.

The table is creating white border and I do not know what is the problem. I have checked the CSS but I do not know how to remove the white border.

Check out:
[electroniccigarettereviewss.com](http://www.electroniccigarettereviewss.com/)

You can see the white border between Rank and Name heading.

Comment: You should post the relevant code here (so when you fix your site this question is still of use to future users), and tell us what you've tried yourself to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the `width` and `float` properties from the `.table_bg` rule.

Comment: Thanks. That was easy fix. But I see the rank images not in the center of the TD, how to fix this?

Comment: Give a larger left margin to `.rank_img`

Answer (score 1):

The widths in your `td`s don't add up to the width of the `table`.
Table rows always want to be as wide as the table itself, so if your `table` is 600 pixels wide, and the total of the `td`s is less, the browser adds a bit to each of the `td`s to make them fit.

In this case, the leftmost `td` that has a width of 83 according to the specs (i.e your source) ends up being 117px wide on the screen.

Solution: calculate manually what the `td` widths should be, or leave the width out of the `table`, or use percentages intead of pixels.